# Are there any questions with an accepted answer which wrongly has negative votes

Tags: discussion

Negative scores on accepted answers upset me. I know "accepted answer" means it helped the OP, not that it is correct.

Nonetheless there are only 72 (according to the latest dump) questions which have an accepted answer with a score less than -1.

Are any of these scores unfair?

(question, accepted votes, highest voted answer)

- [Compare SQL Server Reporting Services to Crystal Reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/168427)  -29     39
- [Built-in types, when (not) to use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/911536)    -17     18
- [Why does PHP software often look better (on the outside) than software written in other languages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/387801)    -16     21
- [Break Statements In the real world](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216359)    -14     47
- [Linux : How to run a server on port 80 as normal user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277991)     -12     35
- [How are CSS frameworks used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/435620)  -9  2
- [PHP templates - with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/163834)  -9  4
- [Getting the array key in a foreach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60032)    -8  4
- [Static Constants in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/842590)    -7  13
- [Is it safe to install SVN on a production win2008 web server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13154)  -7  6
- [What is Windows PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/514492)   -6  20
- [What could be the shortest way of checking function parameter , which might have values  0 , 1 , 2 , 3 in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/821415)  -5  12
- [Programatically align a toolbar on top of the iPhone keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158574)     -5  15
- [ASP.NET MVC: Binding a Complex Type to a Select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/554790)   -4  2
- [Python timedelta in years](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/765797)     -4  9
- [Where can I find a good implementation of Adapter Patterns with good examples in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/812260)  -4  4
- [Code to create CAPTCHA code in ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/430615)   -3  8
- [Consistent hashcodes for dictionaries in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/980390)   -3  1
- [SELECT element in the multiple selection display style without allowing multiple selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/900019)    -3  1
- [How do foreach loops work in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/398982)  -3  32
- [Populating dropdownlist with selectlist in ViewData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/609063)   -3  0
- [How do I find the smallest item in an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/736670)  -3  19
- [What is the best way to extract a version string from a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65994)  -3  5
- [Regular expression to match hostname or IP Address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106179)   -3  6
- [Is there a nullable datepicker that I can bind to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/865572)    -3  4
- [After learning C  should I consider learning Matlab if my emphasis is on Engineering?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/821653)     -3  9
- [Problems executing compiled 3.5 code on a server which only has the 2.0 framework.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/167569)    -3  7
- [UInt32 to Int32](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210383)   -3  3
- [What calculator is an aid to you as a programmer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/418612)     -3  13
- [Regular Expression in Python - Parsing html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/445642)   -3  16
- [Serializable Inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182873)  -3  5
- [How to compile legacy VB6 code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/229868)    -3  6
- [A cool algorithm to check a Sudoku field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/289537)     -3  11
- [Ruby: More flexibility than Java/C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/404676)  -3  6
- [good postgresql client for windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105788)   -3  3
- [Is this the right way to create an XML document from a SQL query in classic ASP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/420371)  -3  4
- [C# Data structure Algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419638)   -2  6
- [Relative date/time for classic ASP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/699686)    -2  1
- [What benefits have you gained from being SAS certified?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/536818)   -2  3
- [Howto: PHP/Javascript communication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/549427)   -2  0
- [pointer to objects within a class, C++ newbie question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/653423)    -2  5
- [how to send signal from one program to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/637870)   -2  5
- [Why use Singleton to manage db connection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/703767)    -2  2
- [Where do you keep your code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/537577)  -2  67
- [How do I find out what type each object is in a ArrayList?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106336)    -2  9
- [LinqToSql Producing Different Sql Queries on Different Machines for Identical Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/269594)    -2  1
- [C# app runs with debugging, but not without](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/738327)   -2  2
- [What's the result of the SQL statement "SELECT DATEADD(s,1234567890, '19700101')"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/546921)    -2  3
- [How to convert an unreadable string back to UTF-8 bytes in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441563)     -2  4
- [PHP Currency Regular Expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/814973)   -2  1
- [Restricted autocompletion on combobox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/868632)     -2  2
- [Python: linking/binding variables together in a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055410)   -2  6
- [XPath search with ElementTree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238697)     -2  1
- [How can I network with other developers at Stack Overflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/188321)    -2  2
- [Make VisualStudio C# have files/folders outside of the project directory.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/717613)     -2  2
- [asp.net Convert CSV string to string[]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73385)     -2  5
- [How much speed-up from converting 3D maths to SSE or other SIMD?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115291)  -2  1
- [REST returning an object graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/387943)    -2  2
- [What is the easiest algorithm to find the day of week of day zero of a given year?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/478694)    -2  6
- [Changing python interpreter windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053794)  -2  4
- [tsql : How to assign a select result to a variable ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/807712)  -2  6
- [byte[] to string to byte array conversion did not work fine in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/891636)   -2  6
- [correct non www users to full www domain name in ASP.Net MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/893781)  -2  1
- [How do I remove a specific number of files using python (version 2.5)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/296490)    -2  4
- [SQL MAX() question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/987389)    -2  4
- [Receiving a Java Method without using getDeclaredMethod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/642532)   -2  3
- [how to stop the execution of current method call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/746548)      -2  3
- [What is best to use between Linq to SQL and the Entity Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/693388)     -2  4
- [Is there a Java unit-test framework that auto-tests getters and setters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/108692)  -2  10
- [What's your favorite "abandoned rule"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/112920)    -2  25
- [How to forcibly close a socket in TIME_WAIT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41602)   -2  8
- [Issue updating a Server Property of a Word doc residing in a Sharepoint folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1004598)   -2  0
- [Python dictionary: are keys() and values() always the same order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/835092)     -2  10
- [Rounded Corners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/812301)   -2  1
- [How to avoid tripping over UTF-8 BOM when reading files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/543225)   -2  3
- [algorithm to check if a space is convex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/971548)   -2  4

Query:

```
select Id, 
    (select max(a.Score) from Answers a where a.ParentId = q.Id ) as MaxScore , 
    (select a.Score from Answers a where a.Id = q.AcceptedAnswerId) as  SelectedScore
into #t
from Questions q
where AcceptedAnswerId is not null 


select '- [' + Title + '](' + 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/' + cast(q.Id as varchar(max)) + ' "link")'
, ' ' + cast(SelectedScore as varchar(max)) 
, ' ' +cast(MaxScore as varchar(max))  
from #t t
join Questions q on q.Id = t.Id
where SelectedScore < MaxScore
and SelectedScore < -1
order by selectedscore asc
```

Comment: should this be cc-wiki?

Comment: only if you intend for people to edit your post

Answer (score 2):

In my slightly biased opinion, my answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277991 is both correct and accepted, in spite of the -12 score.

Answer (score 0):

Accepted answers generally garner more attention than any other answer for a given question. Normally, that will result in a nice little rep bump... but if the answer is wrong, unhelpful, or seen as rude... then the opposite may happen.

*Break Statements In the real world* - selected answer is unnecessarily opinionated... and C programmers don't take kindly to people dumping on their cherished language features.

*How do foreach loops work in C#?* - selected answer is incomplete and wrong.

*How are CSS frameworks used?* - answer is trite and unhelpful. Also, it was posted by asker and then accepted - adding insult to injury is a great way to collect down-votes.

Comment: note shog, you can game the system in this way. post a really atrocious answer, get it accepted, get the big rep bump down, fix it, relish in your new rep.

Comment: Ha! You have a wicked mind, Sam... ;-)

Comment: The Break answer is hopelessly argued, but I think the downvoting is mostly down to the lack of imagination of the downvoters.

Comment: I imagine a world, where no loop is judged by the presence of `break`...